# jQuery callback function - how do I pass this parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I am using a jQuery request and returning it's xhr object. When this is done I am passing this xhr object so that I can build a chart.

See code below:

```
function getPieData() {
        getData('@Url.Action("AjaxPieDataOverdue", "KPIs")').done(createPie, 'overdue');
        getData('@Url.Action("AjaxPieDataApproaching", "KPIs")').done(createPie, 'approaching');
        getData('@Url.Action("AjaxPieDataWithin", "KPIs")').done(createPie, 'within');
    };

    function getData(url) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
    };

function createPie(data, type) {
        alert(data);
        $('#jqxwindow-pie').jqxWindow('open');

        var source =
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
                   { name: 'SectionCount' },
                   { name: 'SectionStatus' }
            ],
            localdata: data
        };

        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, { async: false, autoBind: true, loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { alert('Error loading "' + source.url + '" : ' + error); } });
        // prepare jqxChart settings

        var settings = {
            title: "Desktop browsers share in Dec 2011",
            description: "(source: wikipedia.org)",
            enableAnimations: true,
            showLegend: false,
            legendPosition: { left: 520, top: 140, width: 100, height: 100 },
            padding: { left: 5, top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5 },
            titlePadding: { left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10 },
            source: dataAdapter,
            colorScheme: 'scheme02',
            seriesGroups:
                [
                    {
                        type: 'pie',
                        showLabels: true,
                        series:
                            [
                                {
                                    dataField: 'SectionCount',
                                    displayText: 'SectionStatus',
                                    labelRadius: 100,
                                    initialAngle: 15,
                                    radius: 130,
                                    innerRadius: 50,
                                    centerOffset: 0,
                                    formatSettings: { sufix: '%', decimalPlaces: 1 }
                                }
                            ]
                    }
                ]
        };

        if (type == 'overdue') {
            // setup the chart
            alert("overdue");
            $('#chartContainer-pie-overdue').jqxChart(settings);
        }
        else if (type == 'approaching') {
            alert("approaching");
            $('#chartContainer-pie-approaching').jqxChart(settings);
        } else {
            alert("approaching");
            $('#chartContainer-pie-within').jqxChart(settings);
        }
    }
```

In this example:

```
 getData('@Url.Action("AjaxPieDataOverdue", "KPIs")').done(createPie, 'overdue');
```

overdue is not being passed to my function. I want to use this variable for the if/else block further down. How do I pass this variable?

Comment: Do you mean: `.done(function(data){createPie(data,'overdue');});` ???

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes that's what I wanted. I find callbacks a bit confusing. I know I want to wait for my data to be returned before using it. But I didn't know how to pass that paremeter until I used your suggestion. I'll mark your question as correct if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e.g, you can use anonymous function in `done` callback to pass extra params like this:

```
getData('...').done(function(data){createPie(data,'overdue');});
```